# How to set alias in configureWebpack in vuepress or vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I have set my configureWebpack parameter as below in config.js

```
configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'alias': '/easym/imgs/'
        }
    }

},
```

My folder structure is as below

```
-/easym
--/.vuepress
--/imgs
---/Img1.jpeg
```

Now when I try to call using this alias `![Img1](~@alias/Img1.jpeg)` I defined, I am getting an error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@alias/Img1.jpeg'
> in '/home/user/git/easym/quiz/smallquizzes'

P.S- My image file is located at `/easym/imgs/Img1.jpeg` where `/easym` is my root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue related to the folder's path but using the following got it fixed.

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@myassets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/img')
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped! As my image folder is outside the .vuepress folder, I changed this line to                 `'@alias': path.resolve(__dirname, '../imgs')` and it worked

Comment: don't forget to check answer as solution.